# Timeago + DateJS = NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, iso8601, datejs

I'm trying to use [`timeago`](http://timeago.yarp.com/) ([source](http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js)), with [`datejs`](http://www.datejs.com/), and it's not working. Here's some sample code I'd expect to work (given that `timeago` and `datejs` are loaded):

```
>>> d = new Date()
Mon Jun 21 2010 13:24:37 GMT-0400 (EST) { _orient=1, more...}
>>> d.toISOString()          // datejs.toISOString
"2010-06-21T17:24:37.501Z"   // this is a valid ISO8601 string, I believe
>>> $.timeago(d.toISOString()) // this should work
"NaN years ago"
```

I'd be much obliged for any input as to why this may be failing, and how one could go about fixing or circumventing this problem.

Thank you.

Brian

Comment: out of curiosity what is the name of the interpreter you are using (the source of those '>>>' prompts)?

Comment: @brainjam: The FireBug console in Firefox 3.6.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm the author of Timeago)

The problem lies in the fact that the ISO8601 timestamp output by datejs includes a milliseconds value.  Timeago currently doesn't support this detailed of an ISO8601 timestamp; it only supports a subset of the ISO8601 spec.

This isn't the first time I've heard about this problem; it's time there's a patch to handle the millis.  I created an [issue to track this](http://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/issues#issue/13).  Look out for an upcoming version of Timeago.  Likely v0.9.

**Update:** There's now a new version of Timeago (v0.9) that supports milliseconds in the timestamps.  [Download it here](http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js).  Here's the [relevant commit](http://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/commit/e8e3072d77c2ea6a315075dcde6529588e358a89).

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's true, if `datejs` isn't around, the bug still exists. In the event `datejs` isn't around, the patch should (hopefully) painlessly pass through to timeago's `$t.parse(date_string)`.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following patch to `jquery.timeago.js`, which resolves the problem:

```
diff -r 89cc78838c70 media/js/contrib/jquery.timeago.js
--- a/media/js/contrib/jquery.timeago.js    Mon Jun 21 10:22:12 2010 -0400
+++ b/media/js/contrib/jquery.timeago.js    Mon Jun 21 13:45:32 2010 -0400
@@ -87,8 +87,14 @@
     datetime: function(elem) {
       // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
       var isTime = $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() == "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
-      var iso8601 = isTime ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
-      return $t.parse(iso8601);
+      var date_string = isTime ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
+
+        // for use with datejs @ http://www.datejs.com/
+      if (typeof(Date.parse) == 'function') {
+        return Date.parse(date_string);
+      } else {
+        return $t.parse(date_string);
+      }
     }
   });
```